# Dealing with the test.java in CRF++ toolkit

Tags: nlp

After ***installing CRF++ toolkit***, I try to ***run the program "test.java" under CRF++-0.54/java folder***. For this, ***I type*** :

```
java -cp /home/amira/CRF++-0.54/java/org/chasen/crfpp test
```

But, I have the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: test. Program will exit.
```

In the README file, there is the command **java -classpath CRFPP.jar test -d ../dic**. But, the problem is that I ***don't find the classpath of CRFPP.jar***. Moreover, I don't understand what **../dic** in the command ***refer to***.

Comment: The README and Makefile in the CRF++ java directory are incorrect/incomplete and it's not surprising that you're having trouble with them since your string of questions suggests that you need to learn more about how to compile and execute c++ and java programs, basics like how the classpath works.  Have you tried contacting the CRF++ developers directly?  (The demo does work if you figure out how to fix the Makefile and modify the command from the README, but this is something the developers should really address.)

Answer (score 5):

1. Make changes in the Makefile of the java directory as per your machine settings.
2. Give the correct Java path and the compiler you are using using.
3. Run `make java` in the swig directory.
4. Run `make all` in the java directory.
5. Before running make in the java directory, ensure that you have the model file in the proper location, otherwise it won't open the model file.
6. Run `make test` in the java directory.